# How do I "resuse" a single bind variable in Arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I want to **programatically** create this SQL with single bind parameter with Arel:

```sql
"users"."first_name" ILIKE $1 OR "users"."last_name" ILIKE $1
```

I tried:

```
users = Arel::Table.new("users")
term = Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new("term") # what is the argument even used for?
users[:first_name].matches(p)
                  .or(
                     users[:last_name].matches(p)
                   )
```

But it results in two different bind variables:

```sql
("users"."first_name" ILIKE $1 OR "users"."last_name" ILIKE $2)
```

Is there a way to do this or should I just use `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("$1")` instead of `BindParam`?

Comment: don't think you can do it with `BindParam` because it is just an autoincrement, regardless of the argument (don't know what the argument does). when bind node is added here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/activerecord/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb#L746 (`o.value` is "term") the final value just comes from `@bind_index` here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/activerecord/lib/arel/collectors/sql_string.rb#L15  argument seems totally unused in this scenario.

Comment: Ok thanks @Alex. I guess SqlLiteral is the best choice then?

Comment: i think so, seems like the only option. btw, here is how `BindParam` argument is used https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/activerecord/test/cases/arel/collectors/composite_test.rb#L39

Comment: @Alex do you want to make that into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BindParam` always auto-increments the binding variable, regardless of the argument. When bind node is added here

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/activerecord/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb#L746

```rb
def visit_Arel_Nodes_BindParam(o, collector)
  collector.add_bind(o.value, &bind_block) # o.value # => 'term'
end
```

the final value just comes from an auto-incremented `@bind_index` here

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/activerecord/lib/arel/collectors/sql_string.rb#L15

```rb
def add_bind(bind) # bind # => 'term'
  self << yield(@bind_index)
  @bind_index += 1
  self
end
```

`BindParam` argument is not used at this point. It's used when other collectors are involved when building full `ActiveRecord` query, like `Arel::Collectors::SubstituteBinds` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/activerecord/lib/arel/collectors/substitute_binds.rb#L18

```
def add_bind(bind)
  bind = bind.value_for_database if bind.respond_to?(:value_for_database)
  self << quoter.quote(bind)
end
```

Without making a custom collector class I don't see any other option but `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("$1")`.